# A paper on the relation between Ernst Kummer's work on factorization and structural linguistics (Zellig Harris)

Tags: unique-factorization-domains

Well, since I have been consulting this forum pertaining to the topic of this thread, I find it fair to provide you with the link to my newly-published paper in
http://revistadefilosofia.com/64-03.pdf (one of the most relevant philosophical journals in the Spanish-speaking world, as you can infer for the places it is indexed in). For those of you who can read Spanish it might be interesting.
I hope noone seems this as spam or the like. I just wanted to share my efforts with you, who have helped me to gain some clarity on some issues by interacting with me thus far (and also from on, I assume :))
  I would be delighted to get some feedback from you. Sorry if the paper is somwhat pedantic, but so should it be to have historical rigour, I believe.

Comment: There is no question here. Promoting your own work as a post is not really the purpose of this site.

Comment: Well, I take it as a token of gratitude to the forum....whatever.....I stated in the message:  I hope noone seems this as spam or the like.

Comment: If you want, you might view this thread as an answer to some of my questions in the forum thus far. For instance (to just name one), to this:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081799/unique-factorization-in-human-language-kummer-rings-at-stake